# Updating a value inside a dynamic object in C#

Tags: c#

I have a dynamic type, which consists of multiple objects, and I need to update an object inside that. my problem is that the path to that object is not known in compile time, and I get that path in run time. Something like:

```
string[] pathToObject;
_dynamicObject[pathToObject[0]][pathToObject[1]]... = someValue;
```

That string array can have any number of strings in it. any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: do you know the name of the nested object? I mean the property name

Comment: Are you saying that if `pathToObject` contains the strings `"A", "B", "C"` you would like the code to be equivalent to `_dynamicObject.A.B.C = someValue;`?

Comment: Selman22, the name would be the last string in that array.

Comment: Yes Lasse, exactly like that.

Comment: If the object is `dynamic`, you can do just that: `_dynamicObject.A.B.C = someValue;`

Comment: the problem is that I don't know how many of those strings I'll have, how would I create that path? I thought of iterating and assigning the reference of those to another object and go forward, but it didn't work, like this:

        object temp =_dynamicObject ; 
        for (i;i<pathToObject.Count();i++)
        {
           object temp = _dynamicObject.pathToObject[i];
        }
        temp = someValue;

Comment: You need to write code using both reflection and IDynamicMetaObjectProvider to get to the properties and sub-properties.